# update age is not working in Next-auth . Nextjs App dir

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I been trying to solve it from months but did't find any solution yet . Can you please check my code and provider my any solution .

```
  import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
  import { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";

  export const nextAuthOptions: AuthOptions = {
   providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
     name: "Credentials",
     credentials: {
      username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
      password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
    },
     async authorize(creds: any, req): Promise<any> {
      return {
        username: creds.username,
       password: creds.password,
      };
     },
    }),
   ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, trigger, session }: any) {
     if (trigger === "update") {
     // Extend the session duration by updateAge (in seconds)
     token.exp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + session.maxAge;
     return { ...token, ...session.user };
    }
      return {
      ...token,
       ...user,
     };
   },

   async session({ session, token }: any) {
    session.user = token;
    return session;
  },
 },
 session: {
  maxAge: 20, // 20 in seconds
  updateAge: 15, // Extend session duration by 15 seconds on each request
  strategy: "jwt",
 },
pages: {
  signIn: "/signin", // Custom sign-in screen URL
},
};
```

1. In this code i'm logout after 20 second but i mentioned the update age of 15 second but still it is throwing me to signin page .
2. what i want is if user active between 20 sec the session keep going on and if user inactive for 15 second then he should be logout . i mean that's what update age is supposed to do but it is not doing currently.

if any of you can figure what's wrong here please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Note: This option is ignored if using JSON Web Tokens 
  updateAge: 24 * 60 * 60, // 24 hours
```

According to official doc.